# flutter_html is not parsing some characters in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `flutter_html` package in my app, to parse the html code from my API. But, I am facing a problem that it is not able to parse some characters like arrows and it is not styling the default numbers which are coming from list tag in html code. Is there any solution/alternative for this?

```
/*: Html(
     data: "<body><div>"+widget.dataList[widget.index].description!+"</div></body>",
     style: {
        //'p': Style(color: secondaryTextColor),
        'body': Style(
            color: secondaryTextColor,
            textDecorationColor: secondaryTextColor,
            fontSize: FontSize(bodyText2Size - 1),
         ),
      },
),*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this package

```
html: ^0.15.0
```

you can use:

```
import 'package:html/dom.dart';
import 'package:html/dom_parsing.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

main() {
  var document = parse(
      '<body>Hello world! <a href="www.html5rocks.com">HTML5 rocks!');
  print(document.outerHtml);
}
```

Comment: It is giving me the html code, I want to parse the html code into text, as it should look on a website, keeping the editing according to html text.